# Retry Junit test in java with different parameter

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have Junit test that execute code with parameter,
I want in case of assertion fail to retry once again with another parameter.
For Example

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    boolean res = somelogic(3);
    assertTrue(res);
    // just if false I want to run again :
    boolean res = somelogic(4);
    assertTrue(res);    
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? What value do you expect returning from `somelogic(3);`? Why is there randomness involved? What kind of randomness are we talking about? What is the source code of `somelogic()`. Please [edit] your question with all the information necessary.

Comment: the code has a thread sleep according to the given number, so I want to test with  longer sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that Java supports [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and write your test as:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    assertTrue(somelogic(3) || somelogic(4));
}
```

That way if `somelogic(3)` is false, then and only then `somelogic(4)` will be run to determine the real value of the assertion.